# Was Nikola Tesla aware of Maxwell's equations?

Tags: discoveries, electromagnetism, maxwell, radiation, tesla

Was Nikola Tesla aware of Maxwell's equations or Heinrich Hertz's experimental proof of the former when he worked on his radio device invention?

Comment: It seems Yes and No... See W.Bernard Carlson, [Tesla Inventor of the Electrical Age (2013, Princeton UP)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Tesla/VWyYDwAAQBAJ), page 125: "Tesla followed the work of Hertz and the Maxwellians by reading
the electrical journals, but he possessed neither the inclination nor
the expertise to become involved in the complex mathematical discussions
of the Maxwellians. (Even Hertz himself was slow to engage in
these mathematical discussions, leading Heaviside to remark in 1889
that “I see that Hertz is not a Maxwellian though he is learning to
be one.”)"

Comment: Why any doubt? Tesla was a well-educated person although without a formal degree. What was his opinion about the theories (highly negative) is a different matter.